# VMWare player : Ubuntu 10.04 guest on Win 7 host - network not working

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualization

I have installed Ubuntu 10.04 (64 bit desktop version) on VMWare player over Windows 7 host (64 bit). I am unable to access network. apt-get fails and I am unable to browse the internet. I tried re-installing VMWare tools..it didn't help. I am new to Virtualization and networking. Can someone please help me out?

Output of ifconfig from inside Ubuntu:

```
aadith@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:c6:56:b7  
          inet addr:192.168.182.130  Bcast:192.168.182.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fec6:56b7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:386 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:534 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:36482 (36.4 KB)  TX bytes:58569 (58.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:380 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:380 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:29248 (29.2 KB)  TX bytes:29248 (29.2 KB)

aadith@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Is the guest obtaining an IP? While inside debian type `ifconfig` and post the output.

Comment: are you behind a proxy ? do you use nat or bridged networking on you virtual machine ?

Comment: @Tim updating the question with ifconfig I got from inside Ubuntu:

Comment: @m0ntassar i tried both bridged and nat..neither worked

Comment: @Aadith when you switch to bridged you may have to configure the network manually if there is not a DHCP server on your "real" network that the host is attached to. After switching to bridged mode and rebooting what is the output of ifconfig?